# When i run app in Iphone-X in Xcode 9, it show error - failed assertion: inChannelsPerFrame >= 4, How can i solve this issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, iphone-x

I got the error failed assertion: inChannelsPerFrame >= 4 when I run My application on iPhone X in Xcode 9, in all other dive it executes without any error, anyone has idea to solve this?

Comment: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/error-iphone-8-xcode-9/34713/2

Comment: Hi Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? I faced the same issue.